# Interpolar nome de variável no ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma automação de testes onde tenho uma variável que recebe valores dinâmicos, de acordo com o teste executado.

No caso o conteúdo de cada *element* muda de acordo com os sites acessados. 
Por exemplo:

```
element :formulario, '#resultado'
element :formulario_a, '#resultado-a'
element :formulario_b, '#resultado-b'
```

Criei um *case*, onde tento interpolar o nome da variável, para reduzir o custo escrita de *when*'s no código.

```
case valor
when 'a' || 'b'
  formulario_"#{valor}".click login
else
  formulario.click login
end
```

Ao executar o código recebo o seguinte erro:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `click' for "formulario_a":String
>   from (pry):3:in`formulario'

Como eu faço para dinamizar o nome da variavel?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você deve pegar a referencia para a variável usando "**eval**"

Alguma coisa parecida com isso:

```
var_suffix = valor ? "_#{valor}" || ''
form = eval("formulario#{var_suffix}")
form.set login if form
```

Se não quiser usar o eval, você pode alternativamente usar o "**binding.local_variable_get**"

```
var_suffix = valor ? "_#{valor}" || ''
form = binding.local_variable_get("formulario#{var_suffix}")
form.set login if form
```

Binding é um objeto especial que permite acessar o contexto local de execução. Mais detalhes:
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Binding.html

Comment: Obrigado, resolvido através do primeiro bloco de código. 
      `var_suffix = marca ? "_#{marca}" : ''`
      `form = eval("formulario#{var_suffix}")`
      `form.click`

Comment: Não recomendo que você use o eval. A melhor forma de fazer isso no Ruby seria com o send, ou algo similar, mesmo. =) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902744/when-is-eval-in-ruby-justified

Comment: concordo que o eval tem q ser usado com cuidado. No caso apresentado, nao tem problema algum. Não usaria também o eval na maior parte das situações, e sim o local_variable_get. Por isso coloquei como alternativa.

Answer (score 1):

Seja bem vindo.

Existe diversas possibilidades de você fazer isso, a que mais se aproxima da que você está querendo fazer é utilizando o método [send](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send). Tomei a liberdade de alterar um pouco seu código para poder demonstrar seu funcionamento.

```
def formulario(login)
  puts "FORMULARIO"
end

def formulario_a(login)
  puts "FORMULARIO_A"
end

def formulario_b(login)
  puts "FORMULARIO_B "
end

def do_it(valor, login)
  if ['a', 'b'].include?(valor)
    send("formulario_#{valor}", login)
  else
    formulario(login)
  end
end

login = true
do_it('a', login)

do_it('b', login)

do_it('c', login)
```

O resultado desse código é.

```
FORMULARIO_A 
FORMULARIO_B
FORMULARIO
```

Espero que tenha ajudado.